# In JDK7, is there a way to use ternary operator when moving a file to conditionally use REPLACE_EXISTING?

Tags: java, java-7

I don't like how the code below looks and I'd like to know how I could do it using the ternary operator:

```
if (isIndexed) {
    Files.move(source, destination);
}
else {
    Files.move(source, destination, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

I'm expecting something that looks like:

```
Files.move(source, destination, isIndexed ? xxxx : StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

If there were some kind of "default" copy option I could use, I think that would be what I'm looking for. But the enum for StandardCopyOption doesn't have a "NONE" option.

So I'm probably missing something. What is it?

Comment: The ternary operator in this case makes the code more confusing IMO.

Comment: Questions like this make me question if I agree with Java have ternary operators at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a varargs argument, so you could just set an empty array by `new StandardCopyOption[0]`.

```
Files.move(source, destination, isIndexed ? new StandardCopyOption[0] : new StandardCopyOption[] { StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING });
```

You only need to make the other hand of the condition an array too. You could refactor it to two (local) constants to improve readability.

Comment: +1 because it's a good answer to the question, but I still think the normal if statement is far clearer!

Comment: In that case, wouldn't you have to make both outputs of the ternary operator arrays?  Or is the compiler smart enough to pick that up?